# A simple reqular expression to replace sql conditional operators?

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a class to handle some MySql functions.
For now, I want a regular expression pattern to detect operations.
Please see my code:

```
$a = "user_id <> 2";


$generalOperators = "/[<>|[<][\sA-Za-z0-9]|>|<|=]([\sA-Za-z0-9])/";
$op = "$1";
$asd = preg_replace($generalOperators, $op, $a);
echo $asd;
```

This will echo `user_id 2` as output!
I am new to regular expressions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly output you want , are you saying that this script will give output or need something else

Answer (score 1):

you can also use str_replace() add more item you want to replace

```
$in_str = str_replace(array('<', '>', '&', '{', '}', '*', '/', '(', '[', ']' , '@', '!', ')', '&', '*', '#', '$', '%', '^', '|','?', '+', '=','"',','), array(''), $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a    = "user_id <> 2";
$res  = preg_replace("/[<>]/","",$a);

echo $res;
```

Comment: What all other character you need to replace ?